# Como impedir modificações no template

Tags: php, javascript, html, footer

Olá, eu sou meio leigo em PHP vou aprendendo aos poucos e descobrindo coisas novas. eu gostária de saber como faço para impedir que uma determinada pessoa que possua meu template, tenha a restrição de não poder modificar o footer no caso os créditos do criador. eu trabalhei bastante no template e não gostaria que simplesmente uma pessoa removesse meus créditos. No caso queria que quando essa pessoa modificar qualquer coisa do footer seja // comentando as tags ou ocultando a com css. Redirecionava para uma página pedindo a solicitação de recolocar os créditos a Página fica por minha conta. queria mesmo so o sistema não sei se faz a diferença entre fazer com PHP ou JavaScript de preferencia (PHP) assim ja aprendo.

Comment: Você pode criar um arquivo `.php` para comparar o que a pessoa alterou, caso tenha alterado o `copyright`, você bloqueia o site. Após criar esse arquivo, você pode criptografa-lo com [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/)

Comment: sim obrigado pela ideia. o problema e que não sei como fazer isso :P

Comment: Olha, infelizmente, isso pode ocorrer muito e em praticamente qualquer linguagem e não apenas em templates. Veja se realmente vale a pena criar uma validação para isso pois como sabemos, isso acaba influenciando um pouco o processamento.

Comment: Outra coisa, as vezes você pode precisar de .js e css para seu fonte funcionar. Tente de forma lógica, deixar, se for essa mesmo a sua preocupação, estes scripts de difícil compreensão para quem ver de fora, por exemplo obfuscando o código

Comment: Você pode transformar o .js em hexadecimal. Tem softwares que fazem isso. Porém, como disse, vai pesar um pouco em processamento. mas não custa tentar ne...

Comment: Se você tem acesso à url dos sites que estão no ar com o seu template, pode criar um 'robozinho' pra navegar por eles e procurar no footer os seus créditos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Como o Valdeir Psr já comentou.. você poderia utilizar o ioncube... Mas ainda assim fica passível de engenharia reversa e é possível, em muitos casos, descriptografar o arquivo.

Para saber como usar o ion cube, acesse (em inglês):
https://www.ioncube.com/tutorials/encoder_gui/

Você poderia vincular uma chave de autenticação no template, que também ficaria passível de engenharia reversa e poderia até mesmo causar problemas com o código.

De qualquer forma você vai perceber que é quase impossível de impedir de que alterem o seu código.

Minha sugestão para você é utilizar o tema sob algum licenciamento open source, assim você está protegido por leis internacionais que permite, caso queira, cobrar o devido reconhecimento.

Esta é uma solução que serve somente se o projeto for open source, de código aberto.

Você pode ler mais a respeito no link abaixo (também em inglês):
https://opensource.org/licenses/osl-2.1.php

Abraço!